# Reindex existing Dataframe using IntervalIndex.from_breaks in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `df`

```
0.54881,0.71519
0.60276,0.54488
0.42365,0.64589
0.43759,0.89177
0.96366,0.38344
```

I would like to reindex the df as below

```
(0,10)   0.54881,0.71519
(10,20)   0.60276,0.54488
(20,30)   0.42365,0.64589
(30,40)   0.43759,0.89177
(40,50)   0.96366,0.38344
```

I have the impression this can be done via `pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks`

However, the following code

```
import numpy.random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
numpy.random.seed(0)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),columns=['a','b'])
index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(range(0,60,10))
result = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=df)
```

Output

```
          a   b
(0, 10]  NaN NaN
(10, 20] NaN NaN
(20, 30] NaN NaN
(30, 40] NaN NaN
(40, 50] NaN NaN
```

May I know what is the issue?

Comment: index alignment. Just `df.index = index` would be fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value when create the df

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),columns=['a','b'])
index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(range(0,60,10))
result = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=df.to_numpy())
```

Comment: `from_breaks` That's a new one for me. +1